# white space below footer and above on re sizing window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, removing-whitespace

I am getting white space above and below my footer ,there is a gap coming please check   css is below

```
.footer {
background-image: url("../images/footer_image.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
        }

.footer_bg {
background-image: url("../images/footer_bg.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 101% auto;
height: 232px;
margin-top: 12.1%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a margin of 8px on the body of the page.

I see in the my style.txt you have added

```
!important .body
{ margin:0 !important; 
 padding:0 !important; 
}
```

This needs to be:

```
body
{ 
margin:0 !important; 
padding:0 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw a body margin of 8px in your site. Add this or remove existing.

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

[image: Your body margin]

**Error**
[image]

Comment: i have just added but no response .

Comment: try adding `!important`.
`.body{
margin:0 !important;
padding:0 !important;
}`

Comment: i have added this code in mystyle.css is am going right way?

Comment: yes you are. but i've check the site and still there are no changes. Or you just updated it locally?

Comment: please check it now @a_enriquez

Comment: Fix your css path. I have an error here. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://apptreetechnologies.com/apptreetech/mystyle.css

Comment: http://apptreetechnologies.com/apptreetech/sites/all/themes/apptreetech/css/mystyle.css @a_enriquez

Comment: please refer to the image above to see the error of your site.